# How to shoot 4K video using UIImagePickerController on compatible iPhones?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

After testing my app on an iPhone 6S+, I noticed the videos it produced were only 1080p, despite the fact that it should be capable of recording in 4K. My `UIImagePickerController` is set up like so:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePickerController.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
imagePickerController.videoMaximumDuration = 3600.f;
imagePickerController.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;

[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I thought that perhaps there would be a new `UIImagePickerControllerQualityType` key for selecting 'very high' quality, but 'high' still seems to be the best quality available. Is there a way to enable 4K recording using `UIImagePickerController`, or do I have to roll my own solution using `AVFoundation`?

Comment: I think `UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh = 0,       // highest quality` will do the work, as it is saying 'highest quality'

Comment: Yeah, but I already specify that and it only records in 1080p.

Comment: Oh ok, I haven't get the iPhone 6s :P

Comment: I think you have to enable 4k video recording from the device setting first (http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-record-4k-video-on-iphone-6s-6s-plus/) a

Comment: @souvickcse Interesting; I don't have access to the device at the moment, but since the video it recorded was 30fps this is *probably* not the cause. But I'll ask the owner to enable that setting and try again anyway!

Comment: same here don't have the device to try.. but it might be the issue.. please let me know if it does work or not...

Comment: @souvickcse Just tried it again with the setting applied, video is still 1080p30, so looks like the setting doesn't have any effect on `UIImagePickerController`.

Comment: Okey..So we have to wait for xcode's new version

Answer (score 0):

In some iOS version this was solved and now, doing

picker.videoQuality = .typeHigh

my iPhone is taking 4k videos.